# Network Discovery stopped working on Samba network

Tags: networking, linux-networking, network-share, discovery

I am a software developer trying to help with a network issue (letting you know I don't know what I am doing). We are a very small shop.

We have a Samba network with a dozen or so Linux servers, and maybe 2 dozen users. Network discovery stopped working last week. Users cannot browse to network resources. Most users are Windows 7, I have an Ubuntu box and a Fedora box with the same issue.

I can connect by manually entering resource locations (by name). Windows users can as well, but have to manually connect by IP address.

There have been no intentional changes to the network. We did have a power interruption last week. We have rebooted the router, and the switches.

Can anyone give me some guidance?
Thanks for any help you can offer.

**EDIT:**

We still have this issue. We have one Mac user - Network Discovery works for him.

Comment: Sounds like your WINS or DNS server failed to start or at least have an issue. Have you checked it?

Comment: I am assuming pour router handles dns. Shouldn't the reboot have corrected any potter blip issues?

Comment: If you ping a server, will it return an IP, or did it just say that it can't find it?

Comment: ping returns not found

Comment: Sounds like the issue is on the router then. What kind of router is it? Something like Cisco, or more like the SOHO variety?

Comment: Adtran Netvanta - so more like Cisco I think

Comment: Hmm.. from what i gather, an AOS unit can't act as a dns, only as a dns proxy. So it seems that the dns server is elsewhere...

Comment: That's what I thought...no one here knows of a DNS server...but the AOS should point to it, right?

Comment: Yeah, it should. What dns server do the clients get?

Comment: Everything is set to use the Adtran's IP for DNS...I guess it bounces off based on it's configuration

Comment: Yeah, you need to check on the AOS

Comment: Thanks @Magnus you put me on the path to an answer. I think. Wish I could upvote you

Comment: No worries, glad i could help